# Full screen responsive horizontal website

Tags: fullscreen, horizontal-scrolling, fullpage.js

I am trying to find the best method in order to create a horizontal website, full screen and if possible responsive, minimum width to be for tablets. The thing is that I need also the horizontal scrolling with the mousewheel, and I saw that fullPage.js doesn't support that or at least i couldn't manage to make it work on this plugin.

Anyway, I need an idea on building the template, with full screen sections displayed inline - I will be very grateful for any tip. Thanks.

Comment: the fullPage.js and this one http://www.minimit.com/articles/code-tips/perfect-responsive-fullscreen-backgrounds but i had trouble in making them to be horizontal- i didn;t figure it out - and all kind of tries in my original css which is not full screen - here is a draft of it http://jsfiddle.net/E8G9n/   also i need to mention that i have images as background for each section, a different one- thanks

Answer (score 1):

Making horizontally responsive is bit tricky and requires a lot of effort.. There can be many many design approaches for making it responsive. It can't just be described with JSFiddle snippets..

However, I have something for you that will definitely get you started with "Horizontal Responsive Layout designing"..

This is must guide / tutorial for people who want to get started with Horizontal Responsive approach

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/02/responsive-horizontal-layout/

Comment: Hello, thank you, I am alreday aware of it - i will continue with my searching and tries, it has to be done somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use one of the tools listed in the following links
http://www.cssdesignawards.com/articles/15-excellent-jquery-plugins-to-spice-up-your-sites/44/
http://jquery-plugins.net/scrollit-js-jquery-plugin-for-scrolling-pages

or you could also mix raw js/jquery with anchor links and add animations when clicked. in taht case you can scroll down using mouse wheel and also have fancy animations when a link is clicked 
regarding responsiveness use css media queries

Comment: Hello, for horizontal scrolling i have already make this work - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/ just that, the main problem is to make the horizontal website with fullscreen images as background, and responsive - and to be continous, like when scrolling with the horizontal scroll bar-